# facebook application link to the problem

Tags: facebook

i'm trying to prepare an application for Facebook. application software is created. "*localhost*" tests without any problems but links within the Facebook application is not working... **e.g. "*page.php?page=test*"**... application, using the fan page. the first page is opened, **UserID** and **PageID** data is seamlessly but i click the link to the sample, the data is blank. i tried to **target="_top"** but not work...

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => false,
));
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
$m2_facebook_kullanici_id = $data['user_id'];
$m2_facebook_sayfa_id = $data['page']['id'];
if(empty($_GET['sayfa'])){
    ...working here USERID and PAGEID...
}
if($_GET['sayfa'] == 'guncelle'){
    ...does not work here USERID and PAGEID...
}
```

i wonder what's wrong?
thank you...

---

**basic solved:**

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx',
    'cookie' => false,
));
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$m2_facebook_kullanici_id = $data['user_id'];
$m2_facebook_sayfa_id = $data['page']['id'];

setcookie("facebook_user_id", $m2_facebook_kullanici_id);
setcookie("facebook_page_id", $m2_facebook_sayfa_id);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(empty($_GET['sayfa'])){
    echo '<a href="index.php?sayfa=guncelle">Güncelle</a><br />';
    echo '<h3>Home Page</h3>';
    echo '<strong>User ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_kullanici_id . '<br />';
    echo '<strong>Page ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_sayfa_id;  
}
if($_GET['sayfa'] == 'guncelle'){
    $m2_facebook_kullanici_id = $_COOKIE["facebook_user_id"];
    $m2_facebook_sayfa_id = $_COOKIE["facebook_page_id"];
    echo '<a href="index.php">Back</a><br />';
    echo '<h3>Settings Page</h3>';
    echo '<strong>User ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_kullanici_id . '<br />';
    echo '<strong>Page ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_sayfa_id;  
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

just add the following code to the end of links

```
?signed_request=' . $_REQUEST['signed_request'] . '
```

or

```
&amp;signed_request=' . $_REQUEST['signed_request'] . '
```

a simple example of the application

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }
  return $data;
}
function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
$data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 'a5aaf146542d50c11f55e001c0fb8f31');

$m2_facebook_kullanici_id = $data['user_id'];
$m2_facebook_sayfa_id = $data['page']['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(empty($_GET['sayfa'])){
    echo '<a href="app_fan_page.php?sayfa=guncelle&amp;signed_request='.$_REQUEST['signed_request'].'">Settings</a><br />';
    echo '<h3>Home</h3>';
    echo '<strong>User ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_kullanici_id . '<br />';
    echo '<strong>Page ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_sayfa_id;
}
if($_GET['sayfa'] == 'guncelle'){
    echo '<a href="app_fan_page.php?signed_request=' . $_REQUEST['signed_request'] . '">Home</a><br />';
    echo '<h3>Settings</h3>';
    echo '<strong>User ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_kullanici_id . '<br />';
    echo '<strong>Page ID:</strong> ' . $m2_facebook_sayfa_id;  
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**special thank:** [moguzalp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492258/moguzalp) and Mesut Eyrice